# How to get Memory Usage from Windows Server 2012 R2 in OpenStack

Tags: monitoring, openstack

I have an *Rocky OpenStack cluster*, I want to monitor memory usage of instances.

monitoring of Linux instances is OK but Windows Server instances do not provide any data for memory usage.

I've searched a lot, I've installed *balloon* driver on windows instances but not worked for me. All components are updated to latest version.

So how can I get memory usage data from them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be Install the **Virtio Balloon** driver AND the **Balloon service** in the guest:

1-Open Device Manager and see if there is an unknown PCI device. If so, right click it and install the driver manually from D:\Balloon\2K16\amd64 (or 2k12, 2k8, etc)

2-Now copy the entire amd64 folder into C:\Program Files\ (NOT x86) and rename it "Balloon". So, now you have the amd64 folder from the disc copied as C:\Program Files\Balloon

3-Open an Administrative Command Prompt and cd to C:\Program Files\Balloon

4-Run this command:

```
BLNSVR.exe -i
```

Comment: Thanks it worked!

Answer (score 2):

In PowerShell

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_operatingsystem -Property TotalVisibleMemorySize,FreePhysicalMemory
```

Or

```
wmic os get freephysicalmemory
```

Or

```
systeminfo
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But how to use these commands from outside of windows? I want to monitor them without login to them

Comment: You can pass -ComputerName to Get-WmiObject to run it remotely